# Google Maps mangling KML

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, qgis

I've created KML files of some world regions for display using the Google Maps API. This has been working fine, but one region has recently started displaying as if the data's corrupt. You can see what I mean here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9u3tNbtEyFRMTdwQTdEa0U5S2s/view?pli=1

If I load the same KML in Google My Maps it still displays correctly:

https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=z8mYjxPmAgBQ.kGn7mza0JOSU

It used to display fine, but now even if I roll back to previous versions of the file it displays in this weird way.

The KML regions are created using QGIS's Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Dissolve tool to merge countries (to shp files), which I then save off as KML. Data is from [Natural Earth's ne_50m_admin_0_countries data set](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-cultural-vectors/).

Does anyone know what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that the Google Maps KML rendering engine has some issues.  It works when I use the [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) third party parser to render it, but not when I use the Google Maps Javascript API v3 KmlLayer to render it.

[rendered with geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/eastern-europe.kml)

Note that the performance with third party parsers will depend on the complexity of the KML.  Tile base rendering like used in KmlLayer will almost always perform better.

[issue #8003 in the Google Maps Javascript API ve issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8003)

Comment: That was my fear... If I had 10 such regions what's the performance likely to be like with geoxml3 (it's been a little slow for me previously, possibly down to my ignorance though)?

Answer (score 1):

I thought I was going crazy. This was working for years until some days ago.
I agree it seems to be where polygons cross the "international date line" or anti-meridian. I see straight lines horizontally across the map.
Furthermore I swapped out my KML file for another from a different source, SAME problem. Thanks for restoring my sanity, I wasted a stressful day trying to fix this, I think it is a Google problem.  ps. they work fine in Google Earth.

Comment: I don't know how much it helps, but you could add your details to the [api issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8003)  @geocodezip linked to.