# kml polygon filling/border distortion when zoomed in

Tags: google-maps, kml

I display KML polygons in Google maps.
When zooming in near the border of the polygon, the polygon border and fill becomes distorted and/or disappears.
(areas inside the polygon are not filled, and areas outside are filled).
Zooming back out resolves the issue.
Issue can be reproduced by copying and pasting the kml below into 
http://display-kml.appspot.com/, then zooming in on the Western border of the box.  (zoom in 4 clicks before I see the shading flip inside/outside).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
 <Document>
   <Folder>
     <name>District</name>
     <open>1</open>
     <Placemark>
       <MultiGeometry>
       <Polygon>

<outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>
-92.02,38.53
-92.02,38.52
-92.45,38.52
-92.45,38.53
-92.02,38.53
</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
       </MultiGeometry>
     </Placemark>
   </Folder>
 </Document>
</kml>
```

Images Here:
http://itic.occinc.com/good.png
(and bad.png)  Stackoverflow would not let me post 3 links.

Comment: possibly related [issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8011)

Comment: possible duplicate question: [Google Maps mangling KML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30224755/google-maps-mangling-kml)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has been fixed. Thanks for the report!